# d3: calling brush-functions with different variables

Tags: d3.js

I have drawn 3 graphs,  and created a brush for each one like this:

```
var brush_month = d3.brushX()
        .extent([[xScale_month.range()[0], padding],[xScale_month.range()[1],h_bar-padding ]]) 
        .on("brush", brushmove)
        .on("end", brushend);

var brushg_month = svg_bar1.append("g")
        .attr("class","brush")
        .call(brush_month);

var brush_day = d3.brushX()
        .extent([[xScale_day.range()[0], padding],[xScale_day.range()[1],h_bar-padding ]]) 
        .on("brush", brushmove)
        .on("end", brushend);

var brushg_day = svg_bar2.append("g")
        .attr("class","brush")
        .call(brush_day);

var brush_hour = d3.brushX()
        .extent([[xScale_hour.range()[0], padding],[xScale_hour.range()[1],h_bar-padding ]]) 
        .on("brush", brushmove)
        .on("end", brushend);

var brushg_hour = svg_bar3.append("g")
        .attr("class","brush")
        .call(brush_hour);
```

I have then created a brushend and brushmove function, where depending on which brush is used different variabels (dim and xScale) should be used. And I am not quite sure how you would call the functions with different variables, or if it is necessary to create a brushend and brushmove function for each brush. My brushmove function looks like this, and works fine when only using one brush:

```
function brushmove(){

        if(d3.event.selection != null){

            //map the coordinates of the brushs' ends to the month/day/hour 
            var d0 = d3.event.selection.map(xScale.invert),
                d1 = [Math.round(d0[0]),Math.round(d0[1])];


            // If empty when rounded, use floor & ceil instead.
            if (d1[0] >= d1[1]) {
                d1[0] = Math.floor(d0[0]);
                d1[1] = Math.ceil(d0[1]);
            }


            //filter dimension such that it is within the brush
            if (d1[0] == (d1[1]-1)){

                dim.filter(d1[0]);     

            } else {

                dim.filter([d1[0],d1[1]]);   

            }


        }

        //update everything
        renderAll();


}
```

Comment: One approach is to assign IDs to the brushes (for eg. `.attr('class','brush').attr('id', 'day_brush')` and based on this ID, in the `brushmove()` function, you can switch functionalities (for eg. `if(d3.select(this).attr('id') === 'day_brush')) { ....` and so on.

Comment: Oh yeah of course - that did the trick - thank you very much :)

Comment: Sure no problem! Glad I could help.